# how can I change feature of thread after it is started?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have one thread I have change all parameters before I have start it. But, while running, I have changed one variable of it but it does not reflect the changes. so, how can I change feature of thread after it is started ? I have did like

```
    cons = CON()    # CON is a thread class
    cons.inter = inter
    cons.start()
```

after start if I change cons.inter, the change is not reflected. How to solve ?

Comment: That should work. It would help if you include the relevant sections of your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

If by "features" you mean user-defined attributes of the `Thread` object (as opposed to some `Thread`-class-level-defined attributes, such as the `daemon` attribute), you definitely *can* do it, and it *will* be reflected.